# Procedure conflict when video play

Tags: android, delphi, video

I work with Alcinoe video player From Zeau64 and when the video is playing, stops for msecs and start again.
Every procedure alone works fine but I see I have a conflict with these procedures. The Timer and the tracking mess the system and stops for msecs.
This is my code.

```
procedure TForm9.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ALVideoPlayerSurface1.VideoPlayer.prepare(VidUrl1, True);
  TrackBar1.Max := ALVideoPlayerSurface1.VideoPlayer.getDuration;
end;

procedure TForm9.ALTrackBar1Tracking(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ALVideoPlayerSurface1.VideoPlayer.seekTo(Round(TrackBar1.Value));
  SecPass.Text := FormatDateTime('nn:ss', (Round(TrackBar1.Value) div 1000) / SecsPerDay);
end;

procedure TForm9.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TrackBar1.Value := ALVideoPlayerSurface1.VideoPlayer.getCurrentPosition;
  SecPass.Text := FormatDateTime('nn:ss', (ALVideoPlayerSurface1.VideoPlayer.getCurrentPosition div 1000) / SecsPerDay);
end;
```

Where can i put the TrackBar Tracking control to move the video where i want?
I try the Onclick, OnTap and I have the Tracking to False;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your timer is updating your TrackBar position which in turn fires TrackBar tracking event which causes your program to seek your video position.

I had same problem in the past with my music player. I solved it by adding global variable `Seeking` which I set to `True` on Trackbar `OnMouseDown` event and set to `False` on `OnMouseUp` event. Then in TrackBar Tracking event I check to see if `Seeking` variable is true. If it is I know that I'm manually seeking position in song, if not I know that TrackBar position was updated by my timer, so no seeking is needed.

Comment: Great idea ... Thanks. Works perfect.

Comment: To be honest I wasn't sure it would work. At the time I have written my answer I wasn't on my development machine so I could not test it out. But I knew that using touch screen on mobile devices does still fire various Mouse events so I was guessing that same approach that works on Windows might also work on mobile platforms. And it seems my guess was correct :-)

Comment: This works only if you tap on the line of TrackBar. If you drag the thumb won't work. But it's ok. I put the AlTrackBar from alcinoe and this component have onmouseup and onmousedown for thumb and works when you drag the thumb.